# Why does $(window).width() change while the page is loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I noticed that my scripts were setting widths incorrectly, so I tried the following snippet:

```
var prev;
setInterval(function(){
    if($(window).width()!=prev)
        console.log(prev=$(window).width());
},1);
```

This printed 2 different values: 1464 and 1481. Since these are 17px apart, I'm almost certain this is caused by scrollbars. The second value is the correct value.

Why does `$(window).width()` change without resizing the window? Shouldn't it return the browser window's width, which should be constant?

Comment: all codes inside $(function(){});?

Comment: Including this in a `$(document).ready()` block could do the trick if the width is still in flux until your DOM is fully loaded.  If there's content within the DOM that causes the width to change, you could try `$(window).load()` as well

Comment: Until the window.load or document.ready event is not triggered, the design may change. Also CSS just may be affecting during drawing the page. So always wait until the page is complete. I prefer window.load at dimension calcutions. document.ready still could be too early as I experienced many times i.e. loading fonts, images, other resources parallel in the background.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$(window).width()` is affected by the margin, border and padding.
These can change as the DOM is being loaded.
As mentioned above, make sure you are waiting until `$(document).ready()` before you start looking at / twiddling with the DOM objects.

More info here http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: I realized that I was loading elements using Ajax and causing a scrollbar to show up. The scrollbar changed `$(window).width()`. However, I expected `$(window).width()` to return the width of the browser window, regardless of the scrollbar's existence.

Comment: The `window` object doesn't have margin, border, or padding. So this answer is partly incorrect; `$(window).width()` is **not** affected by margin, border, or padding.

Comment: `window.outerWidth` may work. But, I am not sure if it's cross browser.

Comment: `window.innerWidth` did the trick. `window.outerWidth` adds the width of the window's borders, which isn't what I want.

Comment: _$(window).width() is affected by the margin, border and padding_... **of what?**

Comment: @Linksku Shouldn't you mark the answer as accepted which actually solved the problem? This one seems misguiding to future readers by providing incomplete/wrong information.

Comment: @Falco This was the only relevant answer when I accepted it. The other answer added `window.innerHeight` afterwards.

Answer (score 17):

`$(window).width()` returns the width of the `window` object *excluding* scrollbars (otherwise known as the viewport width). Depending on the operating system and browser, the vertical scrollbar can often subtract from the viewport width. This means you should call this function once all your content has been loaded, and you'll need to call it again if the content changes.

Putting this in the `$.ready()` function won't guarantee that you'll get the correct width with respect to the final page content. This is because `$.ready` fires when the DOM is loaded, but there might still be images/fonts that can affect the layout. It's very possible that a scrollbar can get added *after* you call `$.ready()`. The easiest solution to this problem is to place your call inside the `$(window).load()` function instead, as this fires when all content has been loaded, and there's nothing more to render.

Generally speaking, it's a good idea to set the width on DOM ready, window load, window resize, and any time the content changes. This can be done like so:

```
$(function() {
  var window_width;

  function set_window_width() {
    window_width = $(window).width();

    // do something with window_width
  }
  set_window_width(); // set width on DOM ready

  $(window).on('load resize', set_window_width); // set width on window load and resize

  function custom_load_content() {
    // load / change content

    set_window_width();
  }
});
```

Most (if not all) of the time, the viewport width is what you want. You're probably using the width to perform some calculations and/or resize some elements, and this should always be relative to the viewport, because your CSS is relative to the viewport. But, if for some reason you want to get the width *including* scrollbars, you can use `window.innerWidth` instead ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth)).

Answer (score 1):

In most of the cases, the window width changes with the content, so there must be some ajax call coming which changes some content of the window. You can use browser debug tool and open the network traffic window to see what comes when the window width changes, debug into the javascript file to find which part of window changes with that ajax call, this may help you to find the reason.